# spark dataframe column group and collect_to_list not according to orderBy

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark 2.2.0 dataframe `dtfBase1` as below. BAQ is ID, AAA is date and AAG is numeric value in double.

[image]

And I would like to convert it into the following. The value of AAG should be indexed according to the order of AAA.

[image]

I used the following code

```
val dtfBase2=dtfBase1.orderBy($"BAQ",$"AAA").groupBy("BAQ").agg(collect_list("AAG") as "arrAAG")
```

But apparently in `dtfBase2` the values of AAG seemed followed a random index instead of AAA's order in the original dataframe. How I index elements in arrAAG according to the order of AAA?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're on Spark 2.4+, you can use `array_sort` and `array_join`

```scala
val dtfBase2 = dtfBase1.groupBy("BAQ")
  .agg(array_sort(collect_list(struct('aaa, 'aag))) as "arrAAG")
  .select('baq, array_join($"arrAAG.aag", ",")  as "arrAAG")
```

It creates a struct with the AAA and AAG, collects those in the aggregate and then sorts.  We then concatenate using `array_join`, but just on the `AAG` element of the struct.

Since you're on Spark 2.2, this version should work

```scala
val dtfBase2 = dtfBase1.groupBy("BAQ")
  .agg(sort_array(collect_list(struct('aaa, 'aag))) as "arrAAG")
  .select('baq, concat_ws(",", $"arrAAG.aag") as "arrAAG")
```

Comment: I have spark 2.2.0

Answer (score -1):

I did this and it worked out. Somehow by caching `dtfBase1` with desired orderBy, the order was remembered somewhere and got passed to next step. Feel free to suggest something doing it in one line.

```
val dtfBase1=....orderBy($"BAQ",$"AAA").cache()
val dtfBase2=dtfBase1.orderBy($"BAQ",$"AAA").groupBy("BAQ").agg(collect_list("AAG") as "arrAAG")
```

Comment: I added an update that should work for Spark 2.2  It replaces `array_sort` and `array_join` with functions available in 2.2